# trouble to push objects in array and it alway be empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to select object from ng-repeat list and insert it in a array, then display each attribute of the selected object in a form. My problem is that I can not insert the object in array, but able to select it. I have narrowed down error. The checkList array is always empty no matter how frontend interface interacts with it(click on checkbox). I have no idea what cause this issue?

My code:

In product.view.html:

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p>You're in Product profolio!!</p>
<h3>All Products:</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in vm.allProducts track by $index">
        {{product.id}} -- {{product.product_name}} -- {{product.product_image}} -- {{product.category}} -- {{product.published_time}} -- {{product.store_id}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="bool" ng-change = "vm.sync(bool,product)"> {{bool}}
    </li>
</ul>
        {{vm.checkList}}
        <form novalidate class="simple-form">
        Product Name: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.checkList[0].product_name" /><br />
        product_image: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.checkList[0].product_image" /><br />
        Category: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.checkList[0].category" /><br />
        publish time: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.checkList[0].published_time" /><br />
        store ID: <input type="number" ng-model="vm.checkList[0].store_id" /><br />
        </form>
        - <button ng-click="vm.createProduct(vm.checkList)">Create</button>
        - <button ng-click="vm.updateProduct(vm.checkList)">Update</button>
        - <button ng-click="vm.deleteProduct(vm.checkList.id)">Delete</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="#/login" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a></p>
```

In productController.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ProductController', ProductController);

    ProductController.$inject = ['UserService', '$rootScope'];
    function ProductController(UserService, $rootScope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.allProducts = [];
        vm.checkList = [];
        vm.deleteProduct = deleteProduct;
        vm.createProduct = createProduct;
        vm.updateProduct = updateProduct;
        vm.isChecked = isChecked;
        vm.sync = sync;

        initController();

        function initController() {
            loadAllProduct();
        }

        function loadCurrentProduct(productname) {
            UserService.GetByUsername(username)
                .then(function (product) {
                    vm.product = product;
                });
        }

        function loadAllProduct() {
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products';
            UserService.GetAll(url)
                .then(function (products) {
                    vm.allProducts = products;
                });
        }

        function deleteProduct(id) {
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/';
            UserService.Delete(url,id)
            .then(function () {
                console.log('flash page!')
                loadAllProduct();
                console.log('done!')
            });
        }

        function createProduct(product){
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products';
            UserService.Create(url,product)
            .then(function(){
                console.log('has creaet product!')
                loadAllProduct();
                console.log('done!')
            });

        }

        function updateProduct(product){
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/';
            UserService.Update(url,product)
            .then(function(){
                console.log('has upadte product!')
                loadAllProduct();
                console.log('done!')
            });

        }

        function sync(bool,product){

            console.log("get into sync!");
            console.log(bool);
            if(bool)
            {
                vm.checkList.push[product];
                console.log(vm.checkList);
                console.log(product);
            }
            else
            {
                for(var i=0; i < vm.checkList.length; i++)
                {
                    if(vm.checkList[i].id == product.id)
                    {
                        vm.checkList.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

My page:

[image]

My error shows in console:

[image]

Comment: `vm.checkList.push[product]`: that's not how you call a function. Function arguments are between parentheses, not brackets: `vm.checkList.push(product)`

Comment: @ JB Nizet Thank you for point out this problem!